# Wordpress ACF: Showing Event Button if Event link exists and Date is in future

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

hope you can help.

I need to do the following, this is using Advanced Custom Fields in Wordpress 4.8

Display an Button if

**A: The Event Date has not passed (i.e. the Event is finished)**
AND
**B: The Buy Ticket Link field has a value in it.**

I have succeeded with A using the code below but I cannot work out how to combine this with B, using ACF.

I have looked at the ACF support post about hiding fields and the page is here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/hiding-empty-fields/ but I don't have the skills to combine these two. I would hugely appreciate any help here please.

```
<?php 
$eventDate = get_field('event_date', false, false);
$today = (date('Y-m-d'));
?>          
 <?php if ($eventDate >=$today)  { ?>
      <div class="tickets">
        <a class="btn-primary" href="<?php echo the_field('buy_link') ?>" target="_blank">
        Buy Tickets</a>
       </div>
 <?php 
    } else { ?>
        <div class="tickets">
        <div class="btn-primary" href="" target="_blank" style="color: white">
        This is an old event. Tickets are no longer on sale.</div>
        </div>
  <?php  } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't overcomplicate it -

If you want to have an extra condition, you can specify it in your conditional statement.

```
<?php 
$eventDate = get_field('event_date', false, false);
$today = (date('Y-m-d'));
$ticketLink = get_field('buy_link');

?>          
<?php if ($eventDate >= $today && $ticketLink)  { ?>
  <div class="tickets">
    <a class="btn-primary" href="<?php echo get_field('buy_link') ?>" target="_blank">
    Buy Tickets</a>
   </div>
<?php 
    } else { ?>
        <div class="tickets">
        <div class="btn-primary" href="#" style="color: white">
    This is an old event. Tickets are no longer on sale.</div>
        </div>
<?php  } ?>
```

Read more about your logical operators here : [Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Comment: Worked. Thank you very much for this - elementary to some that know! Much appreciated.